# How does IN query work in SQL

Tags: sql, nosql

```
Select * 
from TableName 
where columnA = value1  
  AND columnB = value2 
  and column3 IN (list of ids);
```

**How will the above query work in either of the DBs.**

How is it different from the following loop query:-

```
for x in list_of_ids:
    Select * from TableName where columnA = value1 AND columnB = value2 and column3 = x;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second example is simply a loop where select will be done X number of times.

The execution first example: 
1. If number of values are small IN will be transformed to ORed conditions. 
2. If number of values are huge some db engines will optimize it and create a spool with all the values and do a join with your table

In any case first example will be faster.

Note: SQL queries are not valid in NOSQL databases. The above scenario is for traditional dbs only.

Answer (score 0):

The later example is not a query. You have a loop (probably Python) that is executing a specific query (with a specific value for column3) each time. 
Is this a fictitious example or taken from a specific DB ?

Answer (score 0):

The first example should be more efficient as it will perform the select * from table once.

The second example will perform the select X times and therefore is likely to be less efficient than the first.

The link below gives the detail on the In clause I think you are after

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4ca39765-6521-4dec-aec1-373b1adf0be7/how-does-the-in-clause-affect-performance?forum=transactsql

Comment: hi Please see revised answer